# Skype bug with windows

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, skype

I have problem with skype(I use Linux Mint). When I run computer all works fine. After 20-40 minutes something happening and I can't see chat window. It looks like this:

[image]

I have one more problem which maybe is related with bug. Sometimes I do not see smileys. I click on *smileys* button, but I do not see popup with smileys.
After reboot system skype works fine. But less then hour. How I can to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you install Skype?

Comment: @blissini I used software manager. On other machines all works fine.

Comment: This looks like QT library bug. Try reinstalling/upgrading QT, and while you're at it, report which QT version do you have. Reporting the exact Skype version wouldn't hurt either, as well as upgrading skype to the [latest version](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/)

Comment: What version of libjpeg do you have installed?

Comment: @coteyr `libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
 libjpeg.so.8 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I ran `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` and answered **Y** on all questions. After this bug was fixed. Now I want to check problem after few hours. I hope the problem disappeared forever.

Comment: I modified the title as "chat bug in windows" suggested it was related to another OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and run:

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer **Y** on all questions. In my case the problem disappeared.

Comment: Great to hear that your problem is solved. Did you by chance take a note which packages were upgraded (I wonder if the issue was QT-related or not)?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev sorry I did not see what packages are updated. I can tell that I answered **Y** near 5 times and system updates ~ 30-40 minutes.